# /^a-eg-h/.match('f') gives null in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

The  expression `/^a-eg-h/.match('f')` gives me `nil` in Ruby interpretor(2.3.1). I'm unable to figure out whats wrong.

Any suggestions ?

Ruby documentations states 'above expression should return `#<MatchData "f">`'.

Comment: Where do the docs claim this? Your regex will only match strings starting with `a-eg-h`. You most likely look for ranges that are defined within `[]`.

Comment: You mean to say `/[^a-eg-h]/.match('f')`, not `/^a-eg-h/.match('f')`.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in the comments, your pattern is incorrect. It appears that you're attempting to use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), but have neglected to include the surrounding square brackets. Your pattern, as it currently stands, will only match on strings that start with the literal text `a-eg-h`. The pattern you want is:

```
/[^a-eg-h]/
```

Additionally, attempting to match the string `j` with this pattern will fail and return `nil` in Ruby, as the string does not match the pattern. A better way to go about this would be something like:

```
match = /[^a-eg-h]/.match(str)
if (match)
    do_something()
end
```

Comment: _"attempting to match the string f with this pattern will fail"_ – what do you mean? `/[^a-eg-h]/.match('f')` works just fine.